# installation of java fx in Eclipse luna fails

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have STS Eclipse Luna

```
Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201503100339
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)
```

and I'm trying to install the java FX plugin but I don't seem to be able to do it. 
I followed the instructions from [here first](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html) and  [then here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse) but no luck as I get the same error all the time "cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions" but in the end it really doesn't give me the alternative solution, it just says that it won't install it.

Is there some kind of dependency that needs to be installed first, or something else that needs to be tweaked in Eclipse? 
I have two separate workspaces one for java 8 and one for 7, I tried on both but no luck. I had a look here on SO but I couldn't find anything specific to Luna, any idea?
thanks

Comment: Why Luna and not Neon?

Comment: The current version of e(fx)clipse requires Eclipse Neon and Java 8.

Comment: right I see, Luna because that's what the company uses, I had no idea that it wasn't compatible with it. Also, can I ask, where did you find that info as I didn't come across it please?

Comment: That first link of yours https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html says 'Download Eclipse 4.6' - and they mean it.